# How does rpm checks md5sum of installed files?

Tags: rpm, md5sum

When does rpm database get populated? specifically, we can check md5sums of installed files using **rpm -V**  .  rpm verifies this against the database. So the question is md5sums in the database will be created during build time or install time?

Answer (score 1):

Build time. If you edit the files in your `%post`, they show as not matching.

You can also write your own `%verify` script that is run on `rpm -V`. For example, you might want to have it re-apply SELinux context to your files.